# Intellij and problems with playtika

Tags: spring, gradle

I keep get this bug randomly from Intellij:
Could not resolve placeholder 'embedded.postgresql.host' doing integration test

embedded.postgresql.host come from playtika
The application is based on spring-boot with spring-cloud

I dont get the error from a terminal for example ./gradlew build

My Intellij is setup to us gradle wrapper

Any one who an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because of spring boot upgrade from 2.3.X to 2.6.X

I found the answer on https://github.com/Playtika/testcontainers-spring-boot

> testcontainers-spring-boot project migrated to Spring Boot 2.4 in
> 2.0.0 version. Please note, that in order to use this project with Spring Boot 2.4, you need to use spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap
> dependency. For earlier Spring Boot (prior to 2.4) users — you need to
> use spring-cloud-starter dependency instead.

I was only making use of spring-cloud-starter not spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap